# Passing data from controller to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I 'm trying to handle data that is coming from my database in a directive , however these data are being pulled by a controller and being assigned to scope like this:

Calendar Controller:

```
'use strict';
var CalendarController = ['$scope', 'EventModel', function(scope, EventModel) {

    scope.retrieve = (function() {
        EventModel.Model.find()
            .then(function(result) {
                scope.events = result;

            }, function() {

            });
    }());

}];


adminApp.controller('CalendarController', CalendarController);
```

Calendar Directive:

```
'use strict';
var calendarDirective = [function($scope) {

    var Calendar = {
        init: function(events) {
            console.log(events);
        }
    };

    return {
        link: function(scope) {
            Calendar.init(scope.events);
        }
    };
}];

adminApp.directive('calendarDirective', calendarDirective);
```

But the data is undefined in the directive, and in the controller the data appears to be ok.

Thanks!

Comment: try with isolated scope

Comment: Please share the directive html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common error for people starting out with AngularJS. This is a load order issue. The events scope variable is not defined when the directive link function is executed. One solution is to use a watch on the variable passed into the directive and load once it is defined.

```
return {
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.$watch('events', function() {
          if(scope.events === undefined) return;

          Calendar.init(scope.events);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: think they mean `$watch`

Answer (score 0):

In the above scenario controller and directives have isolated scope. One solution will be to use factory/service to communicate with the server and inject the service to controller and directive. Since service/factory is singleton you can cache the data & share is between controllers & directives.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

Directive html

```
<calendar-directive objEvent="events" ></calendar-directive >
```

JS :

```
'use strict';
var calendarDirective = [function($scope) {


    return {
        scope : { objEvent : '=objEvent'}
        template: '<div>{{ objEvent }}</div>',
    };
}];
```

Use angular [isolated scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).